# Taking any 2 inputs and show result in third input in JS onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I have a formula:

> Capacity = factor * height

I have to show three inputs on the form for the (Capacity, factor, and height), the requirement is that if a user enters any two inputs the third one must be calculated.

For example, if user inputs capacity and height, factor must be calculated by

> factor = capacity/height

and so on. **Can anyone suggest how it can be achieved by using onChange of any input? Or is there any better way to do it?**

**HTML**

```
 <input id="Factor" min="0" onchange="calculate();" type="number">
 <input id="Capacity" min="0" onchange="calculate();" type="number">
 <input id="Height" min="0" onchange="calculate();" type="number">
```

**JS**

```
function calculate() {
            var capacity = $("#Capacity ").val();
            var height = $("#Height").val();
            var factor = $("#Factor").val();
            if (!capacity || !height || !factor) {
                return false;
            }
            if (height > 0 || factor > 0) {
                $("#Capacity").val(factor * height);
            }
            if (capacity > 0 || factor > 0) {
                $("#Height").val(capacity / factor);
            }
            if (capacity > 0 || height > 0) {
                $("#Factor").val(capacity / height);
            }
        };
```

Comment: I think the problem is still under-specified. You also need to specify how to handle cases when all 3 inputs are non-empty and the user changes one of them. For example: `capacity`=10, `factor`=5, `height`=2 and the user changes `capacity` to `101` (i.e. just adds `1` to the end). What is the expected behavior?

Comment: That's what confuses me. Can you suggest any possible solution?

Comment: There are a few choices. 1) Do nothing (i.e. wait till user clears at lest one of the fields) and probably add explicit "Clear" button 2) Specify re-calculation priorities (e.g. recalculate `capacity` unless it is the focused field in which case recalculate `factor`). 3) less obvious and more complicated: keep track in which order user focused fields and update the one that was focused least recently (or was not focused at all). I think you may come up with a few more ideas.

Comment: Here's a fiddle of the third option suggested by @SergGr  https://jsfiddle.net/ma65yof5/.

Comment: @mark.hch, thanks for putting some code, but I think that the nice point of the strategy #3 is that you don't need to separate cases of 2 and 3 filled in fields. All you need is just pre-initialize `inputOrder` with ids of all 3 fields. You can see it at https://jsfiddle.net/toq7sL5j/

Comment: @SergGr good call! May as well clean it up a bit more, since we don't have to check if it exists in the array to splice it.. https://jsfiddle.net/ba6zv0pg

Comment: @SergGr Thanks guys for your time and efforts. Yes, your solutions helped me. Send the solution as the answer so I can accept it. Thanks again

Comment: @mark.hch Thanks guys for your time and efforts. Yes, your solutions helped me. Send the solution as the answer so I can accept it. Thanks again

Comment: @AbdulAziz, Done. As the code is mostly written by mark.hch, I think you should give him some more time to provide his answer. If he does, I'm quite OK with just upvoting of my answer and giving the accepted answer to him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is still under-specified. You also need to specify how to handle cases when all 3 inputs are non-empty and the user changes one of them. For example: `capacity`=10, `factor`=5, `height`=2 and the user changes capacity to 101 (i.e. just adds 1 to the end). What is the expected behavior? There are a few choices.

1. Do nothing (i.e. wait till user clears at lest one of the fields) and probably add explicit "Clear" button
2. Specify re-calculation priorities (e.g. recalculate capacity unless it is the focused field in which case recalculate factor).
3. less obvious and more complicated: keep track in which order user focused fields and update the one that was focused least recently (or was not focused at all). I think you may come up with a few more ideas.

You may see a demo of the option #3 at [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/toq7sL5j/)

The code of the solution is mostly written by @mark.hch

```
//to hold the order in which inputs were populated
var inputOrder = ['Factor', 'Capacity', 'Height'];
//calculation formulae
function UpdateFactor(c, h) { $('#Factor').val(c / h); }
function UpdateCapacity(f, h) { $('#Capacity').val(f * h); }
function UpdateHeight(f, c) {   $('#Height').val(c / f); }
//tied to keyup, could easily be change too
$('#Factor,#Capacity,#Height').keyup(function() {
    //gather our input numbers as floats
    var f = parseFloat($('#Factor').val());
  var c = parseFloat($('#Capacity').val());
  var h = parseFloat($('#Height').val());
  //get the current element's id
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  //get the index in inputOrder if already present
  var idx = inputOrder.indexOf(id);
  //if the input already had a value, splice it from the inputOrder array
  if(idx != -1) { inputOrder.splice(idx, 1); }
  //add the current input id to the inputOrder array
  inputOrder.push(id);
  //count how many fields are currently filled out
  var ct = 0;
  ct += isNaN(f) ? 0 : 1;
  ct += isNaN(c) ? 0 : 1;
  ct += isNaN(h) ? 0 : 1;
  if(ct >= 2) {
    //update the least recently populated field
    switch(inputOrder[0]) {
        case 'Factor':
        UpdateFactor(c, h);
        break;
      case 'Capacity':
        UpdateCapacity(f, h);
        break;
      case 'Height':
        UpdateHeight(f, c);
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer saved my day